# How can i write this more simple? this is HTML.jason Snipper

Tags: html, code-snippets

"Print to console": {
        "prefix": "log",
        "body": [

```
        "<!-- -->",
        "<section id= >",

        " <div class=", "content-box", ">", "<div class=", "content-title wow animated fadeInDown", " data-wow-duration=", "1s", " data-wow-delay=", ".5s", ">",

        "<h3> </h3>",

        "<div class=", "content-title-underline", "></div>",
        "</div>",
        "</div>",


        "<div class=", "container", ">",
        "<div class=", "row", ">",
        "<div class=", "col-md-*", "></div>",
        "</div>",
        "</div>",
        "</section>",
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

Please, what is the problem with this?

Comment: Your final HTML code should not be enquoted like `"<!-- -->"` or `"<section id="">...</section>"`. You should either escape the outer double quotations or use a valid syntax for your VS Code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

usualy if u want insert a double quote inside a string which start with another double quote yu should write \" but can be even a double double quote like "" 
is depends onw hcih language you writing , assuming you using php you should use \"

Comment: thank! i changed the code but it takes ages to write it with many commas!

Comment: There are even other solution in PHP:

first is to use single quote for start the string or the HEREDOC or NOWDOC format

you can find more details here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php[/link]